# extract a mxn matrix

Tags: list-manipulation, matrix, import, associations, excel

[image]

```
 {{"", "", "ITA", "ITA", "ITA", "EU", "EU", "EU", "RDM", "RDM", "RDM", 
  "ITA", "ITA", "EU", "EU", "RDM", "RDM", ""}, {"", "", "agri", "ind",
   "serv", "agri", "ind", "serv", "agri", "ind", "serv", "cons", 
  "inv", "cons", "inv", "cons", "inv", "tot"}, {"ITA", "agri", 3, 2, 
  4, 10, 15, 1, 1, 5, 2, 20, 0, 16, 0, 10, 0, 89}, {"ITA", "ind", 24, 
  75, 55, 4, 55, 20, 1, 40, 15, 50, 20, 10, 12, 40, 10, 431}, {"ITA", 
  "serv", 8, 47, 30, 1, 44, 32, 1, 25, 15, 68, 2, 20, 2, 12, 1, 
  308}, {"EU", "agri", 3, 1, 1, 120, 120, 35, 70, 105, 22, 38, 1, 379,
   12, 233, 5, 1145}, {"EU", "ind", 15, 55, 45, 225, 650, 166, 12, 
  410, 132, 95, 18, 790, 280, 383, 90, 3366}, {"EU", "serv", 1, 47, 
  25, 95, 374, 430, 120, 410, 340, 65, 12, 920, 15, 650, 10, 
  3514}, {"RDM", "agri", 1, 0, 1, 68, 22, 75, 350, 480, 120, 22, 0, 
  222, 8, 1450, 55, 2874}, {"RDM", "ind", 12, 27, 22, 255, 646, 170, 
  750, 1640, 470, 120, 32, 500, 400, 1450, 220, 6714}, {"RDM", "serv",
   0, 12, 12, 45, 285, 325, 322, 450, 450, 22, 1, 450, 10, 848, 34, 
  3266}, {"", "va", 22, 165, 113, 322, 1155, 2260, 1247, 3149, 1700, 
  "", "", "", "", "", "", 10133}, {"", "out", 89, 431, 308, 1145, 
  3366, 3514, 2874, 6714, 3266, 500, 86, 3307, 739, 5076, 425, ""}}
```

This is my starting point. I've imported the matrix. I'm trying to write a procedure to extract the matrix of "ITA" but I'm not able to create an association. I want to write ITA and get the 3x3 matrix with the respective labels and a 3x2 too. it is important to maintain the two labels.

I show you the result i need to reach (in mathematica) because i don't know if i've explained it well:
[image]

Comment: It is unclear whether what you want is actually two tables, one $3 \times 3$ plus labels and one $3 \times 2$ plus labels, or one table, $3 \times 5$ plus labels.  Do you actually require two sets of labels on each axis or would one set of labels that rendered wide for rows and as two lines for columns suffice?  You have been relatively dismissive of the answers so far, but have not been clear in indicating their deficiencies.

Comment: Sorry i Would be more clear. I want two tables, one 3×3 plus labels and one 3×2 plus labels, but i would like to know a procedure to get this tables recalling them just writing a specific key ( in this case as you see I would like to digit "ITA" and get first the matrix 3x3 with all data of ITA and the in a second moment the 3x2). I require two sets of labels

Answer (score 5):

This `Dataset` based method allows use of the column and row names instead of column and row indices.

`ds` uses a list of two elements for the column and row names since they are in two parts. `data` is the data in the post.

```
ds = Dataset@
  Association[#[[1 ;; 2]] -> 
      AssociationThread[Transpose@data[[1 ;; 2, 3 ;;]], #[[3 ;;]]] & /@ 
    data[[3 ;;, All]]];
```

Now with `ds` selection can be made on the column and row names.

```
Normal@ds[
  KeySelect[First@# == "ITA" &], 
  KeySelect[First@# == "ITA" \[And] ContainsAny[{Last@#}, {"agri", "ind", "serv"}] &]
  ]

(*
<|
  {"ITA", "agri"} -> 
    <|{"ITA", "agri"} -> 3, {"ITA", "ind"} -> 2, {"ITA", "serv"} -> 4|>, 
  {"ITA", "ind"} -> 
    <|{"ITA", "agri"} -> 24, {"ITA", "ind"} -> 75, {"ITA", "serv"} -> 55|>,
  {"ITA", "serv"} -> 
    <|{"ITA", "agri"} -> 8, {"ITA", "ind"} ->  47, {"ITA", "serv"} -> 30|>
|>
*)
```

Similarly for

```
Normal@ds[
  KeySelect[First@# == "ITA" &], 
  KeySelect[First@# == "ITA" \[And] ContainsAny[{Last@#}, {"cons", "inv"}] &]
]
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: This solution works if we work with small database... i would  like to find a way that works with hundreds or even more rows and columns

Comment: Use `MemberQ` instead of `ContainsAny`.  That appears to speed it up some.

Comment: if i use MemberQ, must I write all the labels by myself of it's automatic?

Comment: I'm not certain what it is you are asking.  With `MemberQ` you would replace the existing `ContainsAny` with `MemberQ[{"agri", "ind", "serv"}, Last@#]`. If you want all of the `"ITA"` columns then just do the `"ITA"` search on the columns and not the `\[And]` part of the criteria.

Comment: ok, but if i have i.e. 1000 rows and 1000 columns it is impossible for me to write every headings by my self

Comment: `Normal@ds[
  KeySelect[First@# == "ITA" &], 
  KeySelect[First@# == "ITA" &]
  ]`  gets you all of the `"ITA"` rows and columns.  Correct.  This is what you asked for in your post. "_I want to write ITA and get the 3x3 matrix with the respective labels and a 3x2 too_".  This is what has been provided.

Comment: ok..i'll try and then i'll tell you (thanks for the moment)

Comment: i tried this one and i see that the procedure put togher the 3x3 and the 3x2

Answer (score 3):

I'm sure there's a better way to do this:

```
data = (* OP's data *);
GroupBy[Flatten[MapThread[Append,
                          {Outer[Riffle, Take[data, {3, -3}, 2], 
                                 Transpose[Take[data, 2, {3, -2}]], 1],
                           Take[data, {3, -3}, {3, -2}]}, 2], 1],
        {Take[#, 2] &, #[[3]] &, #[[4]] & -> Last}, Dataset[Map[Last, #, {2}]] &]
```

Comment: Thanks for it, but is not what i looking for

Comment: Well, it was intended as a starting point. Did you notice the first element of the output, for starters?

Comment: sorry, i don't understand what do you mean.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean, either. Did you even look at the output after executing this?